# RubyMotion error: clang Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ruby, xcode, clang, rubymotion

So decided to try out RubyMotion today, but getting error on first step :(

When I run 'rake device' I get the following error:

```
→ rake device        
   Build ./build/iPhoneOS-9.0-Development
   Compile ./app/app_delegate.rb
    clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
    clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
    Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.53)
    Target: aarch64-apple-darwin14.3.0
    Thread model: posix
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
    clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s) - no preprocessable inputs.
    rake aborted!
    Command failed with status (254): [/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Deve...]
    /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:153:in `block (2 levels) in build'
    /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:131:in `each'
    /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/builder.rb:131:in `block in build'
    /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/paralel_builder.rb:47:in `call'
    /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/paralel_builder.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
    Tasks: TOP => device => archive => build:device
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? 
just calling **rake** works fine as a simulator, but issue only arise when I call **rake device**.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
app.archs['iPhoneOS'] = ['armv7']
```

to your rake file. That fixed it for me.

Comment: This has removed the clang segmentation .... error, it is now replaced with: error: ApplicationVerificationFailed which I suspect might be Xcode related issue.